# is there any way o navigate to next page after animation is complete?

Tags: html, css

i am trying to animate button when  click on the green button its goes to 40px left side and then return to its orinal position and when animation  is finished its navigate to next page.
but when i m click on button its directly navigate to next page without any animation.
can someone plz help me how to do it.

1. List item

```css
.defaultBtn {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 23px;
  align-items: center;
}

.defaultBtn input[type=checkbox] {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  display: none;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.defaultBtn a label {
  width: 240px;
  height: 52px;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}

.defaultBtn a label span {
  top: 13px;
  z-index: 2;
  right: 57px;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  position: absolute;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.defaultBtn a label::before {
  content: "";
  width: 130px;
  height: 52px;
  margin-left: 12px;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 35px;
  background-color: #122433;
  background-size: 50px 96px;
  background-position: 5px 0px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url(https://i.ibb.co/HpMQBCz/checkmark.png);
}

.defaultBtn a label::after {
  content: '';
  top: 0;
  right: 18px;
  width: 157px;
  height: 52px;
  position: absolute;
  border: 0.2rem solid #64ef65;
  border-radius: 35px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #53D853 0%, #0F860F 100%);
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked+a label::before {
  animation-name: switchBgColorDefault;
  animation-duration: 0.50s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-timing-function: steps(1);
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked+a label::after {
  animation-name: switchColorDefault;
  animation-duration: 0.50s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes switchBgColorDefault {
  0% {
    background-position: 5px 0px;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 8px -50px;
    background-color: #007236;
  }
}

@keyframes switchColorDefault {
  0% {
    background-color: #00a651;
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  50% {
    background-color: #00a651;
    transform: translateX(-70px);
  }
  100% {
    background-color: #00a651;
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<span>Standard Products</span>
<div class="defaultBtn">
  <input type="checkbox" id="defaultBtn">
  <a href="https://www.google.com/search?q=google+translate&oq=goo&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j35i39l2j0l5.4298j0j15&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8" id="standard"><label for="defaultBtn"><span><strong>Access</strong></span></label></a>
</div>
```

Comment: yes .. you can  do it by js

Answer (score 0):

Instead of keeping the href in a tag you need to handle it in javascript.
You will need to put one click handler in the javascript then you can acheive this.

In HTML

```
 <div class="defaultBtn" onclick="navigate()">
       <input type="checkbox" id="defaultBtn">
          <a href=""><label for="defaultBtn"><span><strong>Access</strong></span> 
         </label></a>
 </div>
```

And in javascript

```
function navigate(){
    setTimeout((function(){
       window.open('https://www.google.com/search?q=google+translate&oq=goo&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j35i39l2j0l5.4298j0j15&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8" id="standard');
    },2000);
}
```

You can change the time.Now i have kept 2 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#standard").click(function(){
  if($('#defaultBtn').prop(":checked",true)){
    window.setTimeout(function(){
      location.reload("https://www.google.com/search?q=google+translate&oq=goo&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j35i39l2j0l5.4298j0j15&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8")},500);
  }
});
```

```css
.defaultBtn {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 23px;
    align-items: center;
  

}
.defaultBtn input[type=checkbox] {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    display: none;
    visibility: hidden;
}
.defaultBtn a label {
    width: 240px;
    height: 52px;
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
}
.defaultBtn a label span {
    top: 13px;
    z-index: 2;
    right: 57px;
    color: #fff;
     display: block;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 600;
    position: absolute;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.defaultBtn a label::before {
   content: "";
    width: 130px;
    height: 52px;
    margin-left: 12px;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 35px;
    background-color:#122433;
    background-size: 50px 96px;
    background-position: 5px 0px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url(https://i.ibb.co/HpMQBCz/checkmark.png);
}
.defaultBtn a label::after {
    content: '';
    top: 0;
    right: 18px;
    width: 157px;
    height: 52px;
    position: absolute;
    border:0.2rem solid #64ef65;
    border-radius: 35px;
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom,#53D853 0%,#0F860F 100%);
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + a label::before{
    animation-name: switchBgColorDefault;
    animation-duration: 0.50s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-timing-function: steps(1);

}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + a label::after{
    animation-name: switchColorDefault;
    animation-duration: 0.50s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;

}
@keyframes switchBgColorDefault {
    0% {
      background-position: 5px 0px;
    }
  
    100% {
      background-position: 8px -50px;
      background-color: #007236;
    }
  }
  
  @keyframes switchColorDefault {
    0% {
      background-color: #00a651;
      transform: translateX(0);
    }
    50% {
      background-color: #00a651;
      transform: translateX(-70px);
    }
    100% {
      background-color: #00a651;
      transform: translateX(0);
    }
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>Standard Products</span>
                                <div class="defaultBtn">
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="defaultBtn">
                                    <a href="https://www.google.com/search?q=google+translate&oq=goo&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j35i39l2j0l5.4298j0j15&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8" id="standard"><label for="defaultBtn"><span><strong>Access</strong></span></label></a>
                                </div>
```